# Утилита на Delphi

Tags: delphi, логирование

В общем такая тема, написал на Delphi утилиту, которая запускается одновременно с компьютером и включает щетчик, который считает время работы программы, а вместе с тем и время работы компьютера. Мне пришла в голову идея, сделать лог файл со всей информацией. Сохранять он должен по нажатию на кнопку(Button1). Получилось так, он  сохраняет но один раз, при последующем сохранении он стирает старый лог и записыает на его место новый.

З.Ы. Лог сохраняется в ТХТ документ.

Comment: А вопрос то в чем? А для чего делать это? 1 - есть функции для извлечения времени работы с последней загрузки. 2 - есть ассемблерная функция (RDTSC), которая дает точнейшее время вообще со старта работы процессора (т.е. с включения компьютера).

Answer (score 2):

Как файл записываете. Rewrite - перезаписать, append - дописать.

Answer (score 0):

```
//var Tfile:TextFile;

AssignFile(Tfile,f);//f-путь

if (FileExists(f)=true) then

begin

Append(Tfile);

writeln(Tfile,Memo1.Text);//Memo1.Text-текст для записи

end

else begin

Rewrite(Tfile);

writeln(Tfile,Memo1.Text);

end;

CloseFile(Tfile);
```